# SwiftUI: How to not show "case none" in a ForEach loop

Tags: foreach, enums, swiftui

Currently, I have a foreach loop that displays all the Icons cases. I want to hide case none because I need a selected case for my EffectIcon view.
ParentView :

```
enum Icons: String,CaseIterable, Hashable {
    case overlayText = "Text"
    case image = "Image"
    case rotate = "Rotate"
    ...
    case none
}
struct EffectPanel: View {
    @State var currentIconSelected: Icons = .none
    @State var listIcons = [Bool](repeating: false, count: Icons.allCases.count)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(0..<listIcons.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        EffectIcon(icon: Icons(rawValue: Icons.allCases[i].rawValue)!, currentIconSelected: $currentIconSelected)
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try something like this to hide the .none cases:

```
ForEach(0..<listIcons.count, id: \.self) { i in
    if Icons(rawValue: Icons.allCases[i].rawValue)! != .none {
      EffectIcon(icon: Icons(rawValue: Icons.allCases[i].rawValue)!,
                 currentIconSelected: $currentIconSelected)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible alternate (just simpler)

```
ForEach(Icons.allCases, id: \.self) { i in
    if i != .none {
        EffectIcon(icon: Icons(rawValue: i.rawValue), currentIconSelected: $currentIconSelected)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Asperi!! This is really opened my mind and I will apply this to all of my code. Also, I really appreciate you for helping me several times!!

Answer (score 1):

You could also add this `static var` to your `enum`:

```
enum Icons {

    static var selectableCases: [Icons] {
        var selectableCases = allCases
        selectableCases.removeLast()
        return selectableCases
    }
}
```